# Swift Closure - Cannot convert value of type (_) -> ()? to expected argument type (() -> ())?

Tags: swift, animation, closures

I am using SideMenuController pod in Xcode 9, Swift 4. Trying to get the side panel animations working. Cant work out why its throwing this error. Thanks in advance if you can help!

```
UIView.panelAnimation( duration, animations: {
        self.centerPanel.frame = centerPanelFrame
        self.set(statusUnderlayAlpha: hidden ? 0 : 1)
    }) { _ in  // THROWS ERROR - CANNOT CONVERT VALUE OF TYPE (_) -> ()? TO EXPECTED ARGUMENT TYPE (() -> ())?
        if hidden {
            self.setSideShadow(hidden: hidden)
        }
        completion?(updated)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of that function:

```
class func panelAnimation(_ duration : TimeInterval, animations : @escaping (()->()), completion : (()->())? = nil)
```

So as you can see, you don’t need the `_ in` keywords at the start of the completion closure.

Rewrite as follows:

```
UIView.panelAnimation( duration, animations: {
    self.centerPanel.frame = centerPanelFrame
    self.set(statusUnderlayAlpha: hidden ? 0 : 1)
}) {
    if hidden {
        self.setSideShadow(hidden: hidden)
    }
    completion?(updated)
}
```